# Set the property required at checkbox in bootstrap

Tags: html, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a simple form with a text-input and two checkbox and I need to set the property "required" at checkbox (I need that at least one of that checkbox is checked).

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail"><?= $this->labelfieldEmail; ?></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="emailField"
        placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="productField"><?= $this->labelfieldProduct; ?></label>
    <div class="controls" >
        <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="widget" name="product[]" <?php if ($this->selectedProduct == "widget") { echo "checked"; }?>/> 
        Widget for website
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="app" name="product[]" <?php if ($this->selectedProduct == "app") { echo "checked"; }?>/> 
        App mobile
    </div>
</div>
```

Please, Any suggests?

**EDIT**

I tried to use jqBootstrapValidation library in the follow way, but it doesn't works:
1. add library
2. Add this into `<head>` tag:

```
<script>
$(function () { 
    $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation(); 
});
</script>
```

3 this is my form code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="<?= $this->baseUrl($this->pathBusinessThankyou);?>">
    <div class="row-fluid">

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <br />
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputName"><?= $this->labelfieldName; ?></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="fullnameField" name="fullname" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail"><?= $this->labelfieldEmail; ?></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="email" id="emailField" name="email" required />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="productField"><?= $this->labelfieldProduct; ?></label>
                <div class="controls" >
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                        data-validation-minchecked-message="<?= $this->validationOneProduct; ?>" 
                        data-validation-minchecked-minchecked="1" value="widget" name="product[]" 
                        <?php if ($this->selectedProduct == "widget") { echo "checked"; }?> />
                        Widget per il tuo sito
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="app" name="product[]" aria-invalid="false"
                        <?php if ($this->selectedProduct == "app") { echo "checked"; }?> />
                        App per il tuo hotel
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail"><?= $this->labelfieldNote; ?></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <textarea rows="3" name="comment" id="commentField"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn input-block-level btn-large btn-success">
                        <?= $this->labelSendRequest; ?>
                        <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JQuery validation plugin for bootstrap forms:

http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/

Comment: Thanks, I'm tring to use that library but it don't works.
I have followed the free step on documetation but it don't works

Comment: Do you have any external link to see what type of problem do you have ?

Comment: thanks a lot, my problem was that don't found the library :D, I had a mistake :D

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run a validation with php while the page has already been loaded. For the validation to work each time you check another box, a script needs to run again to perform the validation. This is much easier to achieve with a jQuery script that executes each time a checkbox is clicked.